# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'musiclibrary.song'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-apps

There is an issue while importing model 'Artist' of my django app in views.py.

```
from musiclibrary.song.models import Artist
```

when I runserver it gives ModuleNotFoundError.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

from musiclibrary.song.models import Artist


def hello_world(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello World!")


def home(request):
    return render(request, "home.html")


def artist(request):
    artist_list = Artist.objects.all().  //// I have to make this line of code work
    context = {'artist_list': artist_list}
    return render(request, 'artist.html', context)
```

Models code:

```
from django.db import models


class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    birth_year = models.IntegerField()
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=150)


class Song(models.Model):
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    release_date = models.IntegerField()
    length = models.DateField()
    artist = models.ForeignKey('Artist', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Error log:

```
  File "/Users/m.zcomputer/PycharmProjects/myFirstApp/musiclibrary/musiclibrary/views.py", line 4, in <module>
    from musiclibrary.song.models import Artist
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'musiclibrary.song'
```

This is how my project is organized

[image]

Comment: How is your project organized?

Comment: `from song.models import Artist`

Comment: @ewokx Please see how my project is organized

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it gives error this way. see pic in the question about how my project looks like

Comment: @SaminSyed: you should mark the `musiclibrary` as source root...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to:

*PyCharm > Preferences > Project > Project Structure*

[Mark this module as Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8y5a.png)

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyQ6b.png)

Apply > Ok

And try again.

Answer (score 1):

you got that error bacause you don't import correctly.

```
from song.models import Artist
```

more :
when you want to import anything from your models.py or etc , you must import them from appname and your appname is song not musiclibrary.